# Plotting graph search in real time

Tags: python, search, plot, graph, visualize

I am applying a modified DFS and I want my python script to plot the graph that it is traversing in real time, so I can see where the search is happening.I have been finding but can't get anything specific. Is it possible to do this without me writing libraries and how if yes?

Comment: It is very unclear what your question is.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the small [streamz](https://streamz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) python package. It relies on [Bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) another python library that can create dynamical plots using javascript. Have a look at [this](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/notebook.html#jupyter-interactors) specific Bokeh example, which might already be close to what you want.

Personally I'm using [Jupyter](http://jupyter.org/) when implementing streams in python.

You are very broad in your problem description which makes it hard to give you a specific answer, but consider this minimal example, maybe this helps you to get started:

```
from streamz.dataframe import Random, StreamingDataFrame

params = {'freq': '2ms', 'interval': '50ms'}
source = Random(**params)

stream_df = (source * 0.5).cumsum()

sdf_params = {
    'row': stream_df.x.rolling('100ms').mean(),
    'very-smooth': stream_df.x.rolling('1000ms').mean()
}

p = StreamingDataFrame(sdf_params).plot()
```

I hope this helps you getting started. Consider to modify you question by providing more details and a clearer problem statement. You'll, in return, certainly get more specific answers.

Comment: Assume that I want to apply [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Pseudocode) and I also want to see where exactly is my script while traversing the graph.like this[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search#/media/File:Animated_BFS.gif) @NKahle